# Unable to change the location in Bing Maps v8 control when Map type is set to Street-Side

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Post initialization of Maps in street-side view,
we are trying to change the location using map.setview with different location coordinates,
map.setview does not work for a street-side view but works with other views like aerial or birdview.

*** MAP Initialisation ****

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
               center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(40.7060179,-74.0110099),
               mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.streetside
               });
```

*** Change Location ****

> Below code does not work

```
map.setView({
       mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.streetside,
       center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(37.027222, -121.0225),
   });
```

> same code works when changed to aerial

```
map.setView({
       mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
       center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(37.027222, -121.0225),
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Streetside imagery is only available for locations along the roads AND where the street side data has been collected before. It looks like the location you passed in does not have Streetside imagery which is why the call is failing. Also if you created the map in Streetside, and your intention is to stay in Streetside but to move to a different location, you don't have to pass in mapTypeId again.

To sum up, using a location close to yours:

```
// Create map - same code as yours
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(40.7060179,-74.0110099),
    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.streetside
});
// Switch to a different location in Streetside
map.setView({
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(37.031969, -121.022367)
});
```